# How to use Translation Workbench for Path Step Rich Text translations

Tags: translation-workbench

When viewing the **Path Step Rich Text** Setup Component in Translation Workbench, EVERYTHING is displayed in a single list.

When specifying a translation, the translator must know the object, the record type and the path step for which the text is associated.
They can't see that in the Translation Workbench UI. They can't filter it either.
How do we use this tool so we can enter translations for the 'correct' text?

***Some ideas :*** 
Export the translations and do it manually and then re-import? 
We've tried that and the Path Text is NOT exported. There are some hieroglyphic internal looking keys that are exported for each of the Path Steps, but no text.

Can't you just read the text anyway and figure it out? Like assume what it relates to?
NO. There are many cases where the 'beginning' of the text (the amount you can see in the workbench anyway) is the same. We can't guess what the text relates to :(